# Change values of some cells in a data frame by Python - change them to the same value from the former row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-sheets

I used pandas and gspread to create a data frame based on a working google sheet. The `dfrname` is my data frame:

```py
sheetwork = client.open('RMA Daily Workload').sheet1
list_of_work = sheetwork.get_all_records()
dfr = pd.DataFrame(list_of_work, columns = ['Date' , '#Order']) 
dfrname = dfr.rename(columns={"Date": "date", "#Order": "value"})
```

The output of my data frame is:
[image: output]

All the "Past" in the date column belongs to the former date, so I want to change all the "Past" in the date column to the former date. For example, change the date in row No.1 to 01/02/2020, and change the date in row No.3 to 01/03/2020.

The reason I want to change them is that I want to add up the values from those two cells so that my final output will be:   `01/02/2020  16`(13+3),  `01/03/2020  5`(2+3) ...

I'm new to python and I know this should be a simple question, but I searched online and didn't find any solutions. I tried so many ways but still cannot work it through. Please advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `where` and `ffill`:

```
dfrname["date"] = dfrname["date"].where(dfrname["date"].ne("Past")).ffill()

>>> dfrname
         date  value
0  01/02/2020     13
1  01/02/2020      3
2  01/03/2020      2
3  01/03/2020      3
4  01/06/2020      5
```

Comment: You're awesome. Thank you! Could you please let me know how I can add the values with the same date so that the date value will be unique? I think I may use `df.sum()`

Comment: `df.groupby("date")["value"].sum()`. For future reference though, please create new posts for follow-up questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Pandas `fillna()` is your friend.

Your `date` values that are all strings called 'Past' should be converted to `NaN`/`None`. Then, you can 'forward-fill' those with the preceding value of the same column.

```
dfrname.loc[dfrname['date'] == 'Past', 'date'] = None
dfrname.fillna(method='ffill')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html